# How to set the default row and column height in openpyxl?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I would like to change the row and column height using Openpyxl.
I can change the specific row and height like this:

```py
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.row_dimensions[1].height = 10
```

But I want to change the default height and width of rows and column so that I don't have to do this for each row and each column.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3) piece of Microsoft documentation, you can have 1,048,576 rows and 16,384 columns.
I searched in openpyxl to find a way to set default column width but could not find a way, even though this is possible in Excel.
I guess the openpyxl does not provide an interface to set this.

You could create a ticket [here](https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl) to request such a feature. However you can also just set the maximum of columns yourself:

```
for i in range(1, 16384):
    worksheet.column_dimensions[get_column_letter(i)].width = 1.89
```

You can do the same thing for the height.